# How to calculate Random Forest manually?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, random-forest, cart, algorithms

I have several questions about the Random Forest algorithm.

1. Is it possible to calculate manually using Random Forest?
2. If we can calculate manually, can you please teach me how can I get this data sample?

   Assume I want to get a price for: -Demand: normal,-Duration: 30min, Distance: 2km
   [image]
3. Does the result we get from calculating manually will match the one we run with the program?

The reason why I ask those questions is that I'm trying to make a pricing system app with Random Forest regression from Sklearn. The app will use that algorithm to calculate prices based on several variables. I also want to know about the mathematical theory about the random forest and how it exactly works, so I can calculate manually and compare the result I get with the result from running the app.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, but it's tedious and time-consuming.
2. The algorithm for random forests is presented on Page 588 of Hastie et al. *[Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print12_toc.pdf)*.  Just follow the instructions.
3. Probably not. Computers will use a different randomization method than you will when constructing the random forest by hand. This is because random forests are *random*, so the results will depend crucially on the results of the randomization.

Another useful resource for learning about random forests is Leo Breiman's 2001 paper "[Random Forests](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebreiman/randomforest2001.pdf)."

Comment: Thankyou for your answer!
I'll check it out first.